# Initialization order of nested classes

Tags: java, initialization, nested-class

I have this piece of code, and the compiler's  returns with NullPointerException where I try to create BtnAct. I've read much about initialization but still haven't come across in what order inner classes are initialized. Can someone help please?

```
public class BaseClass{
    static Myclass myClass;
    public static void main(){
        myClass = new MyClass;
    }
}
class MyClass{
    NewClass newClass;
    public MyClass(){
        newClass = new NewClass();
    }
    class BtnActn extends AbstractAction {
        BtnActn() {
           super("Button");
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //blabla
        }
    }
}

class NewClass{
    JButton button;
    public NewClass(){
        button = new JButton(BaseClass.myClass.new BtnActn()); //NullPointer.ex here
    }                                                          
}
```

Comment: I guess static field `myClass` of `BaseClass` is `null` when you invoke the nested instance class constructor on it.

Comment: What is `BaseClass` and I assume myClass should be `static`.  What do you see when you try to debug your program using your debugger?

Comment: myClass is static. Probably what Mena said is the case, is there a way to tell the initialization methods to stop at a certain level and let the value assignment happen first in BaseClass?

Comment: I don't see how this is ever going to work. BaseClass.myClass isn't going to be assigned until the completion of the contructor, which is going to NPE because BaseClass.myClass isn't assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read much about initialization but still haven't come across in what order inner classes are initialized.

Class initialization is about the initialization of a classes static fields and execution of static initializer blocks.  However, an inner class in Java is not allowed to have any static fields or static initializers. (See [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).)  Hence (real) class initialization for inner classes is moot.  It makes no difference when it happens ... 'cos there is nothing in an inner class to initialize.

The real problem here is that while you have a `static` field, its actual initialization (to a non-null value) is not done during static initialization.  Rather, it *would* happen when some part of your code *explicitly* calls `BaseClass.main()`.  However, none of your code does that ... and hence `myClass` is going to be `null` when you try to use it.

Again ... I stress ... this is not an issue of how static initialization works, because your code doesn't use static initialization to initialize the field in question.

Comment: I thought the value assignment of the instance happens before making additional calls from the instance, but I see how silly that is now. So it's practically impossible to do what I'm trying to do with just the initialization) of MyClass. Although finding a workaround won't be hard. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens:

1. Base class tries to create an instance of MyClass. Please notice that at that time it's not assigned to myClass yet
2. the new instance of MyClass tries to create an instance of NewClass. Please notice that at that time, it's not assigned to the variable newClass yet
3. the new instance of NewClass tries to create a new instance of JButton. For that purpose, it first needs to access BaseClass.myClass. Unfortunately, the object BaseClass.myClass is already in memory (it's in the process of being initialized at that time), but it's not assigned to the BaseClass.myClass variable yet. So it makes a NullPointerException.

So you need to separate the initialization of your Button from the initialization of myClass variable in BaseClass.